# UILabel move right <-> left like Music App

Tags: iphone, animation, uilabel

My UILAbel is too long, and I want user can see all of its.
So I want My Text move from right to left and reverse like Title when song is playing in music app.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Change the UILabel x position by creating a NSTimer that repeatedly fires.  When you get the timer callback, adjust the x position:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5f target:self selector: @selector(bannerTimer:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

- (void)bannerTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    title.frame = CGRectOffset(title.frame, -1, 0);

    //  TODO Handle wrap around
}
```

When the title needs to wrap, set x to the width of the device.  Or, have it move back to the right by increasing the x position.

Comment: I got it https://github.com/sumanthk2006/MarqueeLabel :D